# JAXB customize bindings - skip generated classes from schema

Tags: jaxb

I have a following schema:

```
<xs:element name="Invoice">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        .....
        <xs:element name="InvoiceLines" type="InvoiceLinesType">
        </xs:element>
        .....
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="InvoiceLinesType">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="InvoiceLine" type="InvoiceLineType">
     </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="InvoiceLineType">    
 <xs:sequence>
   .....
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The problem is, that it generate classes:

- Invoice - which contain member of InvoiceLinesType
- InvoiceLinesType - which contain a collection of InvoiceLineType
- InvoiceLineType

So there is one unnecessary class (InvoiceLinesType) and i prefer the following

- Invoice - which contain a collection of InvoiceLineType
- InvoiceLineType

Does anyone know how to tell the compiler not to generate this package (InvoiceLinesType).

My current external binding file is there

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="invoice.xsd" node="/xs:schema"> 
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        .....            
        <xjc:simple/>
        .....
    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Thank You for response.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify your schema - drop InvoiceLinesType and have InvoiceLineType as unbounded element in Invoice.

```
<xs:element name="Invoice">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        .....
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="InvoiceLine" type="InvoiceLineType">
        </xs:element>
        .....
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="InvoiceLineType">    
 <xs:sequence>
   .....
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: The scheme is given. I'm not entitled to change it. It is used inside web service.

Comment: Well then there aren't much you could do with XJC. Why that extra class is bothering you so much?